# How do I add scan credentials for Jenkins Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to set up the [CloudBees Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/chapter-bitbucket.html#bitbucket) but I am unable to set the credentials.  I have added username and password credentials, but the dropdown is still empty.

I am using a new installation of Jenkins version 2.9 with the Bitbucket Branch source plugin version 1.5.

[image]

Here are the credentials I have added.  I also added SSH username with private key in an earlier attempt.
[image]

I installed jenkins using docker and then added the plugins.  Here is the jenkins portion of my docker-compose file

```
jenkins:
image: jenkinsci/jenkins:latest
#image: arcanneero/cd-jenkins-pipeline
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  - "50000:50000"
volumes:
  - ./jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking the _Add_ button and added your username + token there? I also had problems for the Github pendant of this plugin to figure out, of which type the credentials need to be.

Comment: I tried that first.  The documentation says "Only HTTP credentials are accepted in this field" - which I assume is "username and password"

Comment: and what happens when you enter such information?

Comment: It saves the credentials, but nothing ever shows in the dropdown.  I will add an image

Comment: kk.. can imagine that. Are all your plugins up-to-date? I remember some bug where the _Add_ form was empty. Otherwise I have no clue - maybe someone else.

Comment: Plugins are up to date.  I basically just installed jenkins, added the plugins, and tried to create this item/job..

Comment: Is it related to jenkins-pipeline/Jenkinsfile in any way?

Comment: Is that resolved ?  I am still not getting credentials under drop down dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try create credentials at top Jenkins level instead of folder level like you are doing now.

Although, folder level credentials should be usable too. Filed [JENKINS-36066](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36066) to track it.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that, but it does work.  Does seem to be a bug with the folder level credentials though. 
Thanks!